# Redis with WordPress Plugin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, redis

Currently I am making a WordPress plugin that will need to store an access token. I understand that it will have to be stored in a database. I've been told I can store it in a Redis database but I am concerned this will be a problem for users that don't use Redis. The alternative solution I've been thinking of is storing it in the WordPress database. Is this a better solution? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should write your plugin to store this sort of information in the WordPress mySQL instance.  You are correct that most WordPress installations don't have access to Redis. To rephrase that: WordPress can't use Redis (with a very few exceptions).

You don't say much about the tokens you need to store.

If it's one per registered user, you can use the wp_usermeta table.  If it's one only for the whole WordPress installation upon which your plugin is installed, you can use the wp_options table. If some of your WordPress posts/pages have their own token, you can use wp_postmeta.

If you need a whole bunch of these tokens, chosen by something besides users or posts, you may need to have your plugin create a new table in the WordPress database.

Comment: I had a feeling that Redis wouldn't be the best idea. Was just double-checking. I need to store an access token that is through OAuth 2. For something this simple I probably shouldn't make a table just for the plugin, correct? I may have the plugin store more data as well but I am still planning it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is it just one (or a few) OAuth tokens and other persistent parameters for each WordPress instance?  In that case, use options.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API

Comment: For the moment I am guessing it will just be one access token. wp_options sounds like the best option. Do I need to somehow sanitize the token as well? Thanks again!

Comment: The Options API should be sql-injection safe, and OAuth tokens are usually considered OK to store without encryption.

Comment: I tried using add_option and it adds the option but does not store the value. I can have it print the access token so I at least know it's retrieving it. I can then set the access token as a variable. Am I missing a step somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: You stash the option away using `add_option()`. You retrieve it from the WordPress MySQL instance using `get_option()`. You may need to update it using `update_option()`. How do you know "it does not store the value?" Have you read the codex page on `add_option()`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option  Like many API schemes in complex systems, using this one is a bit intricate.

Comment: Will read more about the Options API. I am a newbie to plugin development so thanks for pointing me in the right direction!